# Как заполнить ячейку таблицы на всю высоту?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как эту строку `<tr><td>Строка 1</td></tr>` растянуть на всю высоту?

**Очень важно!** фиксированная высота только у блока `.container` и `table tr:nth-child(2) td` все остальное должно быть динамическое

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px; /* только этот размер может меняться */
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Заголовок</div>
  <div class="content">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Строка 1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Строка 2</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вкратце, хочу получить такой эффект

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px; /* только этот размер может меняться */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
table tr:first-child  {
  height: 100%;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Заголовок</div>
  <div class="content">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Строка 1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Строка 2</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: так я изменил высоту контейнера, для наглядности

Comment: понял, не заметил